# Turn a Callback into a Pointer in JNA

Tags: jna

I must be missing something. Given an instance of a class that implements `com.sun.jna.Callback`, how do I get a function pointer address as a `Pointer`, so that I can pass it to a function that takes a `void*` parameter (I’m using `Pointer`).

Specifically, I want to create a `CFNumber` (aka `NSNumber*`) using [`CFNumberCreate(Pointer, int, Pointer)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNumberCreate) with the address of the function, so that I can call [`SetSpeechProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Speech_Synthesis_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SetSpeechProperty) to register a [`SpeechDoneProcPtr`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Speech_Synthesis_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/SpeechDoneProcPtr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  You pass the callback instance and let JNA handle the pointer conversions.  Make sure you keep a strong reference to the callback object so it doesn't get GC'd.

If you need to, make another function mapping that uses your callback type instead of `Pointer`.

You *can* get the [native pointer value for a callback instance](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.5.2/javadoc/com/sun/jna/CallbackReference.html#getFunctionPointer%28com.sun.jna.Callback%29), but there are very few reasons why you'd ever need to.

Comment: Thanks. Even though it felt strange at first, another `CFNumberRef` constructor that takes a Callback parameter works fine: `public CFNumberRef CFNumberCreate(Pointer alloc, int theType, Callback valuePtr);`

Comment: Actually I just realized that I [need to create a pointer to the function pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17685620/471341). I can’t use `CallbackReference` because it’s not a public class. Do you know a public way to convert a Callback to a Pointer?

Comment: Ooh, that's an oversight.  You can effectively make a `CallbackByReference` by creating a `Structure` with a single `Callback` field, though.  Same memory layout.

Answer (score 0):

I still needed to convert a Callback to Pointer and I found a dirty hack to do it.
Call memcpy() with the Callback with zero length copy.  memcpy() returns the Callback as a Pointer.

For Windows I define the library where memcpy() is found:

```
public interface msvcrt extends StdCallLibrary {
  Pointer memcpy(Callback dst, Callback src, int size);
}
```

And then to use it like this:

```
public Pointer callbackToPointer(Callback callback) {
  msvcrt crt = (msvcrt)Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt", msvcrt.class);
  return crt.memcpy(callback, callback, 0);  //zero length copy returns dest
}
```

Tada!