# Callback function pointer jna

Tags: java, callback

So i have native function in C declared as `int NgSetEvent (int event, long callback)`. long Callback represent the callback function pointer. Callback prototype is declared as `int oncodeline(int code, int documentid, char *string)`. The callback should be registered with method `NgSetEvent`. The problem is how to get pointer to that function which should be long or Nativelong? I have tried a lot of different aproaches but none of them gave a result. Callback was never invoked.

I have tried to do like it says in [Turn a Callback into a Pointer in JNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282785/turn-a-callback-into-a-pointer-in-jna), but with no success. i don't know what to try anymore.
Any help will be appreciated.

OnCodeline

```
public interface OnCodeline extends Callback {
    int oncodeline (int code, int documentid, byte[] string);
}
```

OnCodelineStruct

```
public class OnCodelineStruct extends Structure {
    public OnCodeline onc;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] { "onc" });
    }

}
```

Main class

```
OnCodelineStruct onCodelinStruct;
onCodelinStruct = new OnCodelineStruct();
            onCodelinStruct.onc = new OnCodeline() {
                @Override
                public int oncodeline(int code, int documentid, byte[] string) {
                    System.out.println("This IS a CALLBACK!");
                    return 0;
                }
            };

sbDll.NgSetEvent(0, onCodelinStruct.getPointer().getNativeLong(0));
```

Comment: What is the problem ? You ask how to implement such callback and it seems implemented to me :)

Comment: You are correct i did implemented it, but the problem is that i don't know how to pass argument(callback) to method NgSetEvent(int event, NativeLong callback)? If there was an argument instanceof Callback than is obvious, but since type is NativeLong... and this part confuses me?

Comment: NgSetEvent should be defined as (int, void *) and then just pass a Callback as is (JNA will make it a pointer).  Whatever NgSetEvent is assumes a pointer is a long (dangerous).

Comment: I got this dll file with device so i can't change it, the method is like as it is. And i still have problem understanding this concept what to put in method NgSetEvent. I tried everything that was on my mind, but no result. Callback is never invoked.

This is original method in DLL:
int NgSetEvent (int event, long callback);  and body of callback function: Int oncodeline(int code, int documentid, char *string).